# Is it possible to dynamically display a page according to long tail Google search?

Tags: seo, google, traffic, content, dynamic

Let assume that someone types a long-tail keyword, how would you dynamically generate a page based on those keywords?

Example:
`summer light pink florescent lights` would generate a page with those keywords.

Is there a way to know what keyword someone has searched and which generated content was displayed?
I can do this on Adwords and I was wondering if this is possible with Google Search traffic?

Comment: is this what you are looking for: http://www.davewooding.com/google-adwords-dynamic-keyword-insertion-php-script/ ?

Answer (score 2):

> Let assume someone types a longtail keyword, how do you dynamically
>   generate a page with those keywords?

You cannot dynamically generate a page to appear in search results *after* the search has been run (unless you control the search engine) so you appear to be either asking how highlight the terms a user entered as part of his or her search on your site or how to create spam content.

> Is there a way to know what keyword was searched and display including
>   that keyword?

Yes and no - if a user is logged in with his or her Google account (or using SSL at Google) the HTTP referrer field is not populated and you will not be able to infer the user's search from the referrer field.

If the user is not logged in, you can parse the query from the `q` GET variable in the referrer URL:

`http://www.google.com/url?sa=t&rct=j& [...] q=the%20query [...]`